# What is the syntax to force the use of an index for a join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, syntax, join

The use of the "FORCE/USE/IGNORE INDEX" when doing a straightforward select is well-documented, but it's not clear from the documentation how to do it for a JOIN.

How do you force a specific index to be used for a joined table?

Comment: Have you just asked a question and answered it in second person, after 1 minute? (I know, I know it is 6 years now, I'm just curious)

Comment: @karatedog: yeah, I spent ages trying to find the answer so wanted to document it somewhere. Thought it would be helpful here.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The FORCE/USE/IGNORE goes after the table name you are joining, and after the alias if you're using one.

```
SELECT
  t1.`id` AS `id_1`,
  t2.`id` AS `id_2`
FROM
  `table1` t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  `table2` t2
  FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN (`table1_id`)
  ON (t2.`table1_id` = t1.`id`)
```

Comment: What about 
SELECT
  t1.`id` AS `id_1`,
  t2.`id` AS `id_2`
FROM
  `table1` t1
LEFT JOIN
  `table2` t2
GROUP BY and forcing use index for group?

Comment: The documentation (which is infinitely easier to find these days) does a really good job of showing all available options: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-hints.html