# MySQL use separate indices for JOIN and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I am trying to execute following query

```
SELECT
   a.sessionID         AS `sessionID`,
   firstSeen, birthday, gender,
   isAnonymous, LanguageCode
FROM transactions AS trx
INNER JOIN actions AS a ON a.sessionID = trx.SessionID
WHERE a.ActionType = 'PURCHASE'
GROUP BY trx.TransactionNumber
```

Explain provides the following output

```
1   SIMPLE  trx ALL TransactionNumber,SessionID NULL    NULL    NULL    225036  Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  a   ref sessionID   sessionID   98  infinitiExport.trx.SessionID    1   Using index
```

The problem is that I am trying to use one field for join and different field for GROUP BY.

How can I tell MySQL to use different indices for same table?

```
CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
  `SessionID` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `TransactionNumber` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `CustomerECommerceTrackID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SKU` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AmountPaid` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Currency` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Name` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `Category` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `customerInfoXML` text,
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `TransactionNumber` (`TransactionNumber`),
  KEY `SessionID` (`SessionID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=212007 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `actions` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sessionActionDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `actionURL` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sessionID` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ActionType` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CustomerID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IPAddressID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CustomerDeviceID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customerInfoXML` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ActionType` (`ActionType`),
  KEY `CustomerDeviceID` (`CustomerDeviceID`),
  KEY `sessionID` (`sessionID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15042833 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Thanks

**EDIT 1**: My indexes were broken, I had to add (SessionID, TransactionNumber) index to transactions table, however now, when I try to include trx.customerInfoXML table mysql stops using index

**EDIT 2** [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272399/what-is-the-syntax-to-force-the-use-of-an-index-for-a-join-in-mysql) does not really solved my problem because it's not standard sql syntax and generally not a good idea to force indices.
For ORM users such syntax is a unattainable luxury.

**EDIT 3** I updated my indices and it solved the problem, see EDIT 1

Comment: You want to use different field for comparing. Do you?

Comment: @PremkumarMathivanan I want to use one index for join and different index for GROUP BY. In EXPLAIN output above you can see that MySQL considers two indices but don't use either

Comment: Can you name the fields wanted to have in groupby?

Comment: @PremkumarMathivanan it's `trx.TransactionNumber`

Comment: The columns in your query and the columns in your `create table` statements have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @GordonLinoff could you please elaborate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the syntax to force the use of an index for a join in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272399/what-is-the-syntax-to-force-the-use-of-an-index-for-a-join-in-mysql)

Comment: @miken32 kind of but I have different problem

Comment: What table did `firstSeen, birthday, gender, isAnonymous, LanguageCode` come from ???  If the `CREATE TABLEs` don't match the `SELECT`, I worry that other things are inconsistent.  Please check everything else for consistency.

Comment: @RickJames those are some extra from extra joins I forgot to remove.